# I called av_probe_input_format3(), now I want to call avcodec_find_decoder(), how do I convert the format in a codec?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, format, codec, decoder

So... I'm dealing with a system that has input data coming in buffers (i.e. NOT a file). I want to determine which decoder to create to decompress an audio stream (MP3, WAV, OGG, ...) So obviously I do not know the input format.

I found out that I could determine the format using the `av_probe_input_format[23]()` functions. That part works great, I get a `format` pointer that matches the files that I use as input.

```
AVInputFormat * format(av_probe_input_format3(&pd, true, &score));
```

I can print the `format->name` and `format->long_name` and these are the correct type (so the detection is working as expected).

Now, I'm trying to understand how to convert that `AVInputFormat *` into a `AVCodec *` so I can call `avcodec_alloc_context3(codec)` to create the actual audio decoder.

I found a couple of functions, which I used like so:

```
AVCodecID const codec_id(av_codec_get_id(format->codec_tag, format->raw_codec_id));
AVCodec * codec(avcodec_find_decoder(codec_id));
```

Problem 1. the `raw_codec_id` field is marked as "private" (should not access/use anywhere in your client's code).

Problem 2. the first function always returns `AV_CODEC_ID_NONE` (`0`) so of course the second call fails each time.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there is way to instead create a *generic* decode that will automatically detect the type of audio I have as input? (that is, would that be the only way to make that work?)

Comment: Format refers to the container, which contains one or more AVStreams. Use the codec_id of the AVStream.

Comment: @Gyan At this point, I don't have any `AVStream` in my code... Also the funny thing is that to allocate an `AVStream` it looks like you need to have a Codec already... `AVStream *avformat_new_stream(AVFormatContext *s, const AVCodec *c);`

Comment: After you run avformat_open_input, you should have AVStream.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so the fact is that trying to use these functions directly is pretty much futile. The problem I have with the design is that it forces me to actually have a callback and that callback forces me to have a thread (i.e. I have to somehow feed data from a stream, not a file or such!)

So I can use the `avformat_open_input()` as mentioned by Gyan, only I have to have my own `AVIOContext`. I was hoping I could just call functions with my incoming data and avoid the pipeline concept. The issue here is some background processes could be servers that use `fork()` and thus you need to be really careful (i.e. `fork()` is not friendly with threads).